# alinhamento de uma imagem html css

Tags: html, css, html5, div

Estou aprendendo HTML e CSS agora, e estou com uma duvida.

Ao adicionar minha logo eu só consegui centralizar ela utilizando text-align: center, porem usando float e outros comandos não muda sua posição, gostaria de saber porque isso ocorre e se tem melhores maneiras de manipular a posição de uma imagem.

Obrigado.

Codigo HTML

```
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="logo">
            <img src="logo.png">
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

CODIGO CSS

```
#header{
    background-color: #35b8b0;
    height: 250px;
}


#logo{
    padding-top: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

#logo img{
    max-width: 100%;
}

#container{
    width: 1000px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A imagem é um elemento do tipo `inline`, por isso é correto sim fazer o alinhamento com `text-aling`. Outra coisa é que `float` não é para alinhar, `float` é para um elemento flutuar ao lado de outro. *Tirando isso a forma como vc montou o layout não está muito legal, vc usou valores fixos e não está nada responsivo, mas não vou entrar nesse assunto aqui...*

Se vc quer outras técnicas de alinhamento vc pode colocar a imagem com display:block e usar margin:auto para alinha-la horizontalmente.

Ou então vc pode mudar o `display` do `container` pai da imagem para display:flex por exemplo, e colocar `justfy-content:center` para alinhar no meio. Sem precisar mudar o display da imagem.

Sugiro que leia essa documentação para entender melhor ais coisas

- https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/display
- https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/box_model

Olha a opção apenas mudando as propriedades da imagem, sem mexer no container pai.

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
header{
    background-color: #35b8b0;
    height: 250px;
}

footer{
    clear: both;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #35b8b0;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 30px;
    font-family: monospace;
}

#foto1{
    padding-top:500px;
}

#logo{
    padding-top: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

#logo img{
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.container{
    width: 1000px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="logo">
            <img src="https://placecage.com/100/100">
        </div>
    </div>
</header>

<div id="foto1">

</div>

<footer>Desenvolvido por Arthur Luiz</footer>
```

Answer (score -1):

bom dia.

olha, geralmente se usa o CSS para formatação mas dá pra fazer algumas coisas pelo HTML. recomendo que use algo como isso:

```
<center><img src="imagem.png"></center>
```

e você disse que alguns comandos não estavam funcionando. o que acontece é o seguinte: você deve indentificar a tag que irá receber a formatação. se já fez isso então pode ser que você tenha escrito algo errado.

Comment: A tag Center está obsoleta e não deve ser usada! Apesar de funcionar no momento pode deixar de funcionar a qualquer momento sem aviso prévio quebrando seu layout. Consulte aqui https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center